DiscordAPIError[40060]: Interaction has already been acknowledged. Discord.js
I've been trying to solve this problem for quite some time. I am making a ticket system and it is very annoying that this error appears. There are times it comes out and times it doesn't. I don't know what to do.
const {
  ActionRowBuilder,
  EmbedBuilder,
  ButtonBuilder,
  WebhookClient,
  ModalBuilder,
  TextInputBuilder,
  TextInputStyle,
} = require('discord.js');
const transcripts = require('discord-html-transcripts');

module.exports = {
  data: {
    name: 'cerrarticket',
  },
  async execute(interaction, client, args) {
    const webhook = new WebhookClient({
      url: client.config.webhook.tickets,
    });

    if (!interaction.member.roles.cache.has(client.config.lf.staffRoleId)) {
      return interaction.reply({
        content: 'Only staff can use this!',
        ephemeral: true,
      });
    }

    const modal = new ModalBuilder()
      .setCustomId('closeticket')
      .setTitle('Ticket close form')
      .addComponents(
        new ActionRowBuilder().addComponents(
          new TextInputBuilder()
            .setCustomId('reason')
            .setLabel('Why do you want to close the ticket?')
            .setStyle(TextInputStyle.Paragraph),
        ),
      );

    await interaction.showModal(modal);

    const submitted = await interaction
      .awaitModalSubmit({
        time: 60000,
        filter: (i) => i.user.id === interaction.user.id,
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        return null;
      });

    if (submitted) {
      const reason = submitted.fields.getTextInputValue('reason');

      const channel = submitted.channel;
      const ownerTicket = submitted.guild.members.cache.get(args[0]);
      const attachment = await transcripts.createTranscript(channel, {
        saveImages: true,
      });

      await submitted.update({
        components: [
          new ActionRowBuilder().addComponents(
            submitted.message.components[0].components.map((x, i) => {
              return ButtonBuilder.from(
                submitted.message.components[0].components[i],
              ).setDisabled(true);
            }),
          ),
        ],
      });

      await submitted.followUp({
        content: 'The ticket has entered the closing process correctly!',
        ephemeral: true,
      });

      await submitted.channel.send({
        embeds: [
          new EmbedBuilder()
            .setColor('#701196')
            .setDescription('The ticket will be closed in 5 seconds...'),
        ],
      });

      setTimeout(async function () {
        if (submitted.channel !== null) {
          await submitted.channel.delete().catch((err) => {
            return null;
          });
        }
        return;
      }, 5000);

      return await webhook
        .send({
          content: '<:Vacio:1286828514770812948>',
          embeds: [
            new EmbedBuilder()
              .setColor('#701196')
              .setDescription(`#  Transcript`)
              .setTimestamp()
              .addFields(
                {
                  name: 'Ticket',
                  value: `#${channel.name} (${channel.id})`,
                },
                {
                  name: 'Panel',
                  value: `${channel.name.split('-')[0].charAt(0).toUpperCase() + channel.name.split('-')[0].slice(1)}`,
                },
                {
                  name: 'Owner',
                  value: `**[@${ownerTicket.user.username}](<https://discord.com/users/${ownerTicket.user.id}/>)** (${ownerTicket.user.id})\n<:Vacio:1286828514770812948>`,
                },
                {
                  name: 'Moderator',
                  value: `**[@${submitted.user.username}](<https://discord.com/users/${submitted.user.id}/>)** (${submitted.user.id})`,
                },
                {
                  name: 'Reason',
                  value: `${reason}`,
                },
              ),
          ],
          files: [attachment],
        })
        .catch((err) => {
          return null;
        });
    }
  },
};

Information:
I'm using Discord.js version 14.15.3 and Node v20.16.0.
Console error:
DiscordAPIError[40060]: Interaction has already been acknowledged.
    at handleErrors (C:\Users\Usuario\Bots Discord\LegoFamily\node_modules\@discordjs\rest\dist\index.js:730:13)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at async BurstHandler.runRequest (C:\Users\Usuario\Bots Discord\LegoFamily\node_modules\@discordjs\rest\dist\index.js:835:23)
    at async _REST.request (C:\Users\Usuario\Bots Discord\LegoFamily\node_modules\@discordjs\rest\dist\index.js:1278:22)
    at async ModalSubmitInteraction.update (C:\Users\Usuario\Bots Discord\LegoFamily\node_modules\discord.js\src\structures\interfaces\InteractionResponses.js:236:5)
    at async Object.execute (C:\Users\Usuario\Bots Discord\LegoFamily\src\Buttons\Tickets\Options\cerrarTicket.js:58:13) {
  requestBody: { files: [], json: { type: 7, data: [Object] } },
  rawError: {
    message: 'Interaction has already been acknowledged.',
    code: 40060
  },
  code: 40060,
  status: 400,
  method: 'POST',
  url: 'https://discord.com/api/v10/interactions/1287607767476994129/aW50ZXJhY3Rpb246MTI4NzYwNzc2NzQ3Njk5NDEyOTo3T2R0ZlNzN0tJbG5TUTQ2d0NkdHNPNndMdHN6QVNpN2p6cGxNU3ZxeXRzdEJVN2ZFV3Y3SFk5UmhwdEdadWNqUHFFcm9JQ29zVk96aTVKMzR4eGxIYUlKdFZCMlV6eEVjclBTbTJDbGMwZTRpSjJvclhrdWlNSEJ6cmxoNEZjRg/callback'
}

I want to fix that annoying error. I tried many things but I don't know what could be the reason why it is appearing. I need help!

Appears to be from your await submitted.update({ ... }) call

Yes, that's where it comes from, but I don't know what to do. It's strange because that error doesn't appear every time the button is used, only sometimes.

Have you try to defer your response?
